# XSLT transformation: accessing inline mapping

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping, document

I am having problems with inline structure and accessing it in xslt:

I have written a transformation which is transforming xml to xml.
For some values i have to look up a key-value-mapping, which i have specified in my stylesheet like this:

```
<map:mappings>
   <mapping doi="DOI_VALUE1" name="NAME1"/>
   <mapping doi="DOI_VALUE2" name="NAME2"/>
</map:mappings>
```

In my transformation i will access this mapping like this:

```
<elementXY>
   <xsl:value-of select="document('')//map:mappings/mapping[@name=$var]/@doi"/>
</elementXY>
```

This is working great, but as 3rd party software is involved -which does not like the "document('')" function- i am looking for another possibility/alternative.

If additional information is required, i am happy to give it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to `exsl:node-set` or similar you can use

```
<xsl:param name="mappings-rtf">
<map:mappings>
   <mapping doi="DOI_VALUE1" name="NAME1"/>
   <mapping doi="DOI_VALUE2" name="NAME2"/>
</map:mappings>
</xsl:param>

<xsl:variable name="mappings-ns" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" select="exsl:node-set($mappings-rtf)"/>
```

and then you can use `<xsl:value-of select="$mappings-ns/map:mappings/mapping[@name=$var]/@doi"/>`.

For efficiency you might want to define a key `<xsl:key name="map" match="map:mappings/mapping" use="@name"/>` and then you can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="$mappings-ns"><!-- need to do this to change context document -->
  <xsl:value-of select="key('map', $var)/@doi"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working, nevertheless i was able to change the 3rdparty Software.